# Inifinite scrolling duplicate record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have academies listing ..I have implemented infinite scrolling but while listing the record, records is getting duplicate values

index.html.haml

```
   #academies
    = render "academy",academy: params["search_form"]
  .container.text-center
    .col-sm-12
      #page_links.pagination-text.scroll-pagination
        = will_paginate @academies
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#academies').append('<%= j render(@academies) %>');
<% if @academies.next_page %>
$("#page_links").hide();
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@academies) %>');
<% else %>
$('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
<% sleep 1  %>
```

academies.coffe.erb

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.scroll-pagination').length
   $(window).scroll ->
   url = $('a.next_page').attr('href')
   if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() -       $(window).height() - 50
    $("#page_links").show()
    $('.pagination').html("<img src='<%= asset_path 'loader.gif' %>' alt='Loading...' title='Loading...' />")
    $('.pagination').delay(100)
    $.getScript(url)
$(window).scroll()
```

I don't know where I'm getting wrong please help me out 
Thanks

Comment: Please post both the method for this page and the `@academies.next_page` method

Comment: thanks for comment....anyways i have solved it adding escape_javascript instead of j and added render "academy"...it works for me